# How to add a click event listener for list in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a child component which will show list of search result. For some reason onclick event is not firing which is sometimes.

So as an alternative i am trying to add click event to search list.

Here is the component

```
<ul class="slds-listbox slds-listbox_vertical" role="presentation">
      <template for:each={records} for:item="record">
         <li key={record.Id}  data-id={record.Id} role="presentation" data-name={record.Name} data-icon={record.icon} data-class="myList">
              <span class="slds-lookup__item-action slds-lookup__item-action--label" role="option">
                    <lightning-icon class="slds-icon slds-icon--small slds-icon-text-default" icon-name={record.icon} alternative-text={objName} size="small"></lightning-icon>
                          <span class="slds-truncate" style="font-size:13px;">{record.Name}</span>
              </span>
         </li>
      </template>
</ul>
```

JS

```
 connectedCallback(){
    //this.template.querySelector('li').addEventListener('click',this.handleSelectTag.bind(this));
    // this.template.querySelector('li').
    
    // this.template.querySelector('myList').addEventListener('click',this.handleSelectTag.bind(this));
    // window.addEventListener('click',this.handleSelectTag.bind(this));
    let e = this.template.querySelectorAll('li[data-class="myList"]');
    console.log("setupAssisstants---<", e[0]);                //This is getting undefined
    e[0].addEventListener("click", this.handleSelectTag)
}
```

I am getting the querselectorall result as null. Can anyone please help to point out what am i doing it wrong

Comment: This is an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). This question presumes the position Y (that you need to add event handlers dynamically), but it won't work. You should bind directly in the template, if possible. If you're still having problems, ask about *that* problem instead. This solution can't work, as during connectedCallback(), no elements have been rendered yet.

Comment: @NBR, out of curiosity, why are you using a custom attribute for the class, instead of using class?

Comment: @glls I did it for a try. I tried with using class attribute.But wasnt working

Comment: querySelector is returning undefined because connectedCallback runs when the component is connected to the DOM, it has not rendered yet, the way eventloop can get tricky is sometimes it would render by the time flow reaches the queryselector line. A bad route would be to delay the connectedcallback, and a good route would be to bind it directly in the template 
         <li key={record.Id}  data-id={record.Id} role="presentation" data-name={record.Name} data-icon={record.icon} data-class="myList" onclick={handleSelectTag} >

Comment: yeaa,I tried binding it. But for some reason it will not fire which is not everytime

Comment: @sfdcfox Before I was directly binding in the template. But for some reason the onclick event was not firing which is sometimes. But it still fires sometimes. Still couldn't figure out what is the reason.

Comment: @NBR We need to figure out why you were having a problem with that solution. This approach isn't ideal.

Comment: @sfdcfox The issue is not consistent

Comment: Yes, but we might be able to help. We want to help. We want you to get the right answer.

Comment: This issue is with onblur. Sometimes when  i select from list onblur is getting fired.

Comment: The issue got resolved by adding some mill seconds to settimeout which was placed inside onblur